# Python: needs more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, syntax

What am I doing wrong to get this error?

```
    replacements = {}
    replacements["**"] = ("<strong>", "</strong>")
    replacements["__"] = ("<em>", "</em>")
    replacements["--"] = ("<blink>", "</blink>")
    replacements["=="] = ("<marquee>", "</marquee>")
    replacements["@@"] = ("<code>", "</code>")

    for delimiter, (open_tag, close_tag) in replacements: # error here
        message = self.replaceFormatting(delimiter, message, open_tag, close_tag);
```

The error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       for doot, (a, b) in replacements: ValueError: need more than 1 value to
>   unpack

All the values tuples have two values. Right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be:

```
for delimiter, (open_tag, close_tag) in replacements.iteritems(): # or .items() in py3k
```

Comment: That he did. General question though, why not:

....
for delimiter in replacements:
    open_tag, close_tag = replacements[delimiter]
....

Comment: @qor721: unpacking earlier is more efficient and idiomatic, I'd say

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to call `.items()` like the third example in [this link](http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/using-iterator-on-a-dictionary-100130.html)

```
for delimiter, (open_tag, close_tag) in replacements.items(): # error here
    message = self.replaceFormatting(delimiter, message, open_tag, close_tag)
```